# Sending commands from iPhone to Android

Tags: java, cocoa-touch, ios4, tcp, android-2.2-froyo

I need to send some commands using the wireless network from an iPhone application to an Android application. I thought a possible way would be to send the commands as strings over TCP (SOAP seemed a better solution, but it seems some libraries would be necessary and it is not necessary). Is there anyone out there who can address me to some documents or some place to start this kind of applications?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this question is that you need to listen on a specific port number by opening a Server Socket on the Android side, and from the client side (iPhone) open a socket connection towards the Android's IP address and port.

Luckily sockets are a pretty standard thing nowadays and behave typically the same across operating systems, that is Linux, Windows, Mac OSX, and iPhone iOS, Android and Symbian.

The only difference you have is which programming language you need to use. On Android you have to use Java. So if an Android application is waiting for the connection your application needs to open a [ServerSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and listen of incoming connections.

From the iPhone part, your application needs to be developed in Objective C. Nothing fundamentally different, but the programming language is different.

Comment: Another option may be to use only C/C++ code under both Android and iPhone with the BSD sockets. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes you can, although as far as I know C/C++ on Android is not that popular unless you really need access to native resources. The development kit for C/C++ is there so I guess you can use it if you prefer.